# How to access prisma studio when the app is already deployed on heroku

Tags: heroku, next.js, prisma, heroku-postgres

I have a `next.js` app which im developing locally right now on development environment. Im calling on `npm run dev` my server and im running prisma studio with `"dev": "next dev -p 3006 & npx prisma studio -p 3007",`

Im wondering how I can access prisma studio if my `next.js` app is already deployed on `heroku` for example. Prisma provides a guide about deploying to `heroku`, but there it is not mentioned how to access the database via prisma studio after deployment.
https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/deployment/deployment-guides/deploying-to-heroku

Does anybody have some experience here?

Comment: Can't you access it in the same way with your project's URL and the port?

Comment: this would mean everyone could see the live database having the url and port. actually, that would be really bad

Comment: Pretty sure there is a way of authentication or alike. People are not totally unaware of security concerns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Prisma Data Platform](https://cloud.prisma.io/) to access Prisma studio for your deployed Heroku application.

The feature is called [Data Browser](https://www.prisma.io/docs/data-platform/data-browser). It can be used to view and edit your application data.

You can invite collaborators and can also provide read/write permissions for your data.

[image: Data Browser]

Comment: can you please provide more info on how this can be done?  Why is the new project in the dashboard asking me to connect to a repo?